# Contour integration of sinh

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I know the answer but don't how to solve follows:

$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sinh \alpha x}{\sinh x} d x=\pi \tan \frac{\pi \alpha}{2},(0<\alpha<1)$

I got a hint about [integral route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3ofC.png), but still can't solve especially upper line and half circle integral.
I just found that the side integrals cancel each other.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\bbox[15px,#ffc]{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\sinh\pars{\alpha x} \over \sinh\pars{x}}\,\dd x =
\pi\tan\pars{\pi\alpha \over 2},\phantom{mm}(0<\alpha<1)}}$

---

\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\sinh\pars{\alpha x} \over \sinh\pars{x}}\,\dd x & =
2\int_{0}^{\infty}{\pars{\expo{\alpha x} - \expo{-\alpha x}}/2 \over \pars{\expo{x} - \expo{-x}}/2}\,\dd x
\\[3mm] & =
2\int_{0}^{\infty}{\expo{\pars{\alpha - 1}x} - \expo{-\pars{\alpha + 1}x} \over 1 - \expo{-2x}}\,\dd x
\\[3mm] & \stackrel{x\ =\ -\ln\pars{t}/2}{=}\,\,\,
2\int_{1}^{0}{t^{1/2 - \alpha/2} - t^{1/2 + \alpha/2} \over 1 - t}\,\pars{-\,{\dd t \over 2t}}
\\[3mm] & =
\int_{0}^{1}{t^{-1/2 - \alpha/2} - t^{-1/2 + \alpha/2} \over 1 - t}\,\dd t
\\[3mm] & =
\int_{0}^{1}{1 - t^{-1/2 + \alpha/2} \over 1 - t}\,\dd t -
\int_{0}^{1}{1 - t^{-1/2 - \alpha/2} \over 1 - t}\,\dd t
\end{align}

With identity
[$\textbf{6.3.22}$](http://people.math.sfu.ca/%7Ecbm/aands/page_259.htm) the last expression can be written in the following form:

\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\sinh\pars{\alpha x} \over \sinh\pars{x}}\,\dd x & =
\Psi\pars{{1 \over 2} + {\alpha \over 2}} -
\Psi\pars{{1 \over 2} - {\alpha \over 2}}
\end{align}

where $\ds{\Psi}$ is the Digamma Function. With
[Euler Reflection Formula $\textbf{6.3.7}$](http://people.math.sfu.ca/%7Ecbm/aands/page_259.htm) :

\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\sinh\pars{\alpha x} \over \sinh\pars{x}}\,\dd x & =
\pi\cot\pars{\pi\bracks{{1 \over 2} - {\alpha \over 2}}} =
\bbox[15px,#ffc,border:1px groove navy]{\pi\tan\pars{\pi\alpha \over 2}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\sinh(ax)}{\sinh(x)}\,dx = 2\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{ax}-e^{-ax}}{e^x-e^{-x}}\,dx = 2\int_{0}^{+\infty}(e^{ax}-e^{-ax})\sum_{n\geq 0}e^{-(2n+1)x}\,dx $$
equals
$$2\sum_{n\geq 0}\left[\frac{1}{2n+1-a}-\frac{1}{2n+1+a}\right]=4a\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2-a^2} $$
i.e. a meromorphic function with simple poles with residue $-2$ at any odd integer. Just like the RHS ;-)